# How can I maintain TeX code layout when pasting into a LyX ERT inset?

Tags: formatting, lyx, copy-paste

When I paste TeX code from a text editor in an ERT inset in a LyX document, the text layout from the text editor is lost, I have to enter the newlines and the tabulations manually in order to regain the original layout.

Is there some way I can paste into LyX without losing the formatting?

I am using Lyx v2.1.2 (16 sep 2014) on a Debian OS.

Comment: This is hardly related to the TeX part of LyX functionality but purely the editor part. So I would recommend asking the developers instead.

Comment: Ik, I have just posted this message on gmane.editors.lyx.devel. I will keep this updated according to what they answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>Try</del> I almost always use Edit → Paste Special → Plain Text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

I am using LyX Version 2.1.2 2014-09-23 on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! “Try” might sound as if you're not certain it works. Does it on your system?

Comment: Yes, it works on my system (Windows). I don't know if the keyboard shortcut is the same on Linux.

Comment: Is the same shortcut on Linux.

Comment: It also works on my Debian distrib. Thanks Hugo!